# Nifi JoltTransformRecord UUID in default transform not working as expected

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a Nifi workflow which uses [JoltTranformRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-jolt-record-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.jolt.record.JoltTransformRecord/index.html) for doing some manipulation in the data which is record based. I have to create a default value uuid in each message in flow file. 
My JoltTranformRecord configuration is as below.

[image]

Jolt specification :

```
[{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
        "payload": "data.payload"
    }
}, {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
        "header": {
            "source": "${source}",
            "client_id": "${client_id}",
            "uuid": "${UUID()}",
            "payload_type":"${payload_type}"
        }

    }
}]
```

Shift operation and all other default operations are working fine as expected. But UUID is coming same for all the messages. I need different UUIDs for each messages. I don't want to add another processor for this purpose only.

My workflow below :

[image]

Reader & Writer configurations for JoltRecord processor is :

IngestionSchemaJsonTreeReader ( From JsonTreeReader Processor ):

[image]

IngestionSchemaAvroRecordSetWriter ( From AvroWriter Processor ) :

[image]

Configured schema registry has below schemas defined in it.

```
com.xyz.ingestion.pre_json

{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "event",
  "namespace": "com.xyz.ingestion.raw",
  "doc": "Event ingested to kafka",
  "fields": [
          {
            "name": "payload",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "string"
            ],
            "default": "null"
          }
        ]
  }


com.xyz.ingestion.raw -

  {
  "type": "record",
  "name": "event",
  "namespace": "com.xyz.ingestion.raw",
  "doc": "Event ingested to kafka",
  "fields": [
    {
      "type": {
        "name": "header",
        "type": "record",
        "namespace": "com.xyz.ingestion.raw.header",
        "doc": "Header data for event ingested",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "payload_type",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "uuid",
            "type": "string",
            "size": "36"
          },
          {
            "name": "client_id",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "source",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ]
      },
      "name": "header"
    },
    {
      "type": {
        "name": "data",
        "type": "record",
        "namespace": "com.xyz.ingestion.raw.data",
        "doc": "Payload for event ingested",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "payload",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "string"
            ],
            "default": "null"
          }
        ]
      },
      "name": "data"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The expression language is evaluated per record. `UUID()` is executed for each evaluation. So `uuid` must be unique for each record. From the information you provided I cannot see why you are getting duplicate `uuids`.

I tried to reproduce your problem with following flow:

[image]

**GenerateFlowFile**:

[image]

**SplitJson**: configure `$` as `JsonPathExpression` to split Json array into records.

**JoltTransformRecord**:

[image]

As you can see the way I am adding the UUID is not different from how you do it. But I am getting different UUIDs as expected:

[image]
[image]

Comment: My reader and writer are different. Screen shot attached. Updated complete screen shot of workflow.

Comment: Also is splitJson processor record based one ? I don't think so.

Comment: Done. Added schema configurations as well.

Comment: @BillGoldberg from the information you provided I cannot see any reason why you are getting the same UUID all the time. The only thing I noticed is that you've set a size property on the UUID attribute in you avro schema. But according to the avro spec it is only used for the "fixed" type. Try the solution I proposed and work your way up gradually to your use case. I used "SplitJson" to split the Json array into Json objects (records) to mimic your ListenTCPRecord, which emits records.